# Reuse $view->result after getting field values row by row

Tags: views, 9

Inside a `hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)` implementation, when I try to get and use field values from `$view->result`, I could no more use `$view->result`; the execution is interrupted with no explicit errors displayed.

```php
function custom_divers_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'localisation_front' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    // This code works.
    \Drupal::logger('custom_divers')->notice(print_r($view->result, TRUE));

    foreach ($view->result as $result) {
      // Getting this value works.
      $type_value =  $result->_entity->type->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
      \Drupal::logger('custom_divers')->notice("type_value: ".$type_value);
    }

    // This code doesn't work.
    \Drupal::logger('custom_divers')->notice(print_r($view->result, TRUE));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: no it is an extract

Comment: Please post the full code. What you have posted shouldn't create the problem that you describe, so the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: ok full code added

Comment: Anything in the server/php logs?

Comment: Ok I found in apache logs "Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted" for the second \Drupal::logger call